# AFNetworking downloading images in a UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, afnetworking

I have a `UITableView` which asynchronously downloads images using `AFNetworking` for every cell in the table.

The download is utilizes a transition for a smooth look and feel and everything works great except for one minor bug:

When I scroll down fast it seems that a new download starts for every image so when I stop scrolling each cell blinks for a few seconds displaying all the images which were "**assigned**" for the cell until it stops with the right image (the latest one).

Is there a way to stop the download once the record is no longer relevant to the cell or to make sure the image displayed is the right one for the cell?

Comment: Can you post your downloading of images code?

Comment: Download "NPRImageView" and check it once...! https://github.com/nicnocquee/NPRImageView and user this method in cellForRowIndexpath: - (void)setImageWithContentsOfURL:(NSURL *)URL placeholderImage:(UIImage *)placeholderImage

Answer (score 0):

You can save the image into dictionary with the key being the indexpath of cell. So when you scroll it check whether the key is present in dictionary and show the image.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   //Cell creation
   //Other cell operations

   NSArrary *keys = [dictImage allKeys]

  if([keys containsObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",indexPath.row]]){
     cell.imageView.image = [dictImage objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",indexPath.row]];
  }
  else{
     //Download the image
     //When download finishes save the image into dictionary
     //Alloc init the dictImage in viewDidLoad
     //Remove the objects of dictImage when reloading with new images
     [dictImage objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",indexPath.row]];
  }
}
```